# How i can change the users path in Windows 11

Tags: windows

How i can change the users path in Windows 11 from c:\users\userX to d:\users\userX?

My DELL notebook has only 128GB SSD C: drive and all time is full. I need to transfer users profiles to drive D:

Tks!

Answer (score 1):

> How i can change the users path in Windows 11

**First:** Just relocate individual large folders (My Documents, My Videos, My Photos and like into Drive D:). Windows allows you to move these folders.

I strongly recommend that you keep the basic USERS folder in Drive C: because Windows has hooks in many other folders (AppData and like).

So **do not move** USERS itself.

**Second:**  128 GB for a main drive is simply too small.

Windows 11 will be around for a few years, so replace the drive with a much bigger SSD drive and overall you will find that much easier.

Trying to manage with a tiny main drive and a big slow hard drive takes too much effort.